# Display 0,1 For Sex in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql

How to generate sex as 0 and 1 for male female in datagridview. I have tried with below code and it displays True Or False for Sex

```
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select   Institution as'Institution(4)', Branch as 'Branch(3)', CustomerCode as 'CustCode(10 Digit)', LastName as 'LName(18)',FirstName as 'Fname(18)',AccountNo as 'AccountNum(Max 20)',Currency as 'Currency(3)',AccountType as 'Account type(2)',CardProduct as 'Card Product(4)', Sex as 'Sex(1)',HomeCity as 'HomeCity(20)',MaritialStatus as 'Married(1)', MobileNo as 'Mobile No.(10)',Email as 'E-mail' from MasterTable where CreatedDate=@CreatedDate", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", dateTimePicker1.Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sdap = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        sdap.Fill(dtt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtt;
        connection.Close();
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))` to avoid the need for `connection.Close();`. It won't solve your problem, but a good habit to get into. Also for the `command`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just you pass this things in your select query. using CASE

```
CASE WHEN  Sex=0 then 'Female' WHEN  Sex=1 then 'Male' END as Genderdisp
```